# Unable to bind MAC Address with interfaces in ubuntu

Tags: networking, 20.04, netplan, aws, systemd-networkd

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on an AWS environment. While trying to bind MAC Address to interfaces in netplan YAML file. The changes are not working as expected.

I followed the following configuration, the system gets up however the binding doesn't work.
I tested the similar configuration on a physical machine and on VMware instance, in all the network interface gets up but macaddress to interface binding doesn't work.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
              macaddress: 00:50:56:b3:86:48
      addresses:
      - 10.10.10.10/24
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.10.10.2
        - 8.8.8.8
  version: 2
```

Later I twisted the network yaml file as follows, The network interface failed to come up in AWS instances and if I manually executed the command "/sbin/ip link set eth0" the netowrk interface gets up. However, in physical and VMWare instances, it worked as expected, i,e, interface up and macaddress to interface mapping working fine.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
              macaddress: 00:50:56:b3:86:48
      addresses:
      - 10.10.10.10/24
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.0.10.2
        - 8.8.8.8
  version: 2
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/920020/netplan-not-spoofing-mac-as-expected